# AutoComplete texinput : Struts 2.1.8.1, jsp, ActionClass

Tags: jsp, autocomplete, struts2

I'm trying to create an autocomplete text input.

I've heard that it's also best now to use `<sj:autocompleter>` rather than `<sx:autocompleter>` because dojo is deprecated but I'm stuck.

I want to know how I can call a method in my Action class and get that displayed on the JSP.

I've seen others that suggest in the `struts.xml` to extend a package from `json-default`.

I tried that then my class wouldn't work (because it's defined in a different package).

I've cut the files down to bare so here's what I have, please help:

pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<!--  Struts 2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-sitemesh-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Complete application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC 
    "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="baseCarsAction" class="com.microed.cars.web.BaseCarsAction" singleton="false" >
            <property name="carsService" ref="carsService"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="homeAction" class="com.microed.cars.web.HomeAction" singleton="false" parent="baseCarsAction" >
    </bean>

    <bean id="carsService" class="com.microed.cars.business.CarsService" singleton="false" >
        <property name="carsDAO" ref="carsDAO"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="carsDAO" class="com.microed.cars.dataaccess.CarsDAO" singleton="false" />
</beans>
```

Complete home.jsp (note my comment 'how do i get results here')

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
        "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

    <s:form action="index" >
      <s:url id="loginURL" action="login" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="transBlock">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span7 offset1">
                <s:textfield name="searchTags" cssClass="span7" placeholder="%{getText('placeholder.search.home')}" />      
            </div>

            <div class="span2 offset1" title="<s:text name='tooltip.search.keywords'/>" >
                <s:submit key="button.search" method="searchTags" cssClass="btn btn-success span2" id="btnSearch" />        
            </div>

            <!--  after calling getData in action class - how do I display it here? -->
        </div>

      </div>
    </s:form>
```

Complete HomeAction:

```
package com.microed.cars.web;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class HomeAction extends BaseCarsAction {
    /** How do I call this when user inputs into a text field? **/
    public void getData() throws SQLException {
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return INPUT;
    }

}
```

Base Action class to inject service:

```
package com.microed.cars.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;

import com.microed.cars.business.CarsService;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class BaseCarsAction extends ActionSupport {

    protected CarsService carsService;
    protected String searchTags;

    @Required
    public void setCarsService(CarsService carsService) {
        this.carsService = carsService;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the s2jquery plugin sample apps? It's unclear where exactly you're running in to a problem.

Comment: Yes, and when I use 'Action or 'ParentPackage annotation my code does not then compile :o/ I guess I need to add dependencies but I don't know which ones.. or if I do, then if they're compatible with Struts 2.1.8.1 I'm really stuck :o(

Comment: AFIAK the Convention plugin existed and worked fine in 2.1.8.1. But it should be relatively straight-forward to convert even if it wasn't; if you're having issues at the *framework* level I'd suggest taking a step back and getting some familiarity with the environment before proceeding much further. Put a minimally-failing project on github and I'll take a look.

Comment: I've committed it here: https://github.com/KenAlton/Cars Many thanks for taking a look

Comment: I don't see any autocomplete stuff in there at all. I'd recommend creating a standalone project without SiteMesh and Spring and work out your autocomplete issues before adding a bunch of other frameworks and functionality.

Comment: Thanks for looking but your comment is correct - there's no autocomplete because I took out every attempt (that did not work).  I don't know why I just don't get the examples - I can't get them to work - the only one I had working was one that prepopulated a list then used that to autocomplete - but that is no good as the list could be huge :o/

Comment: And besides - I really don't know which way to go - as I mentioned, i hear dojo is depricated and it's not wise to use it - I see things about js:autocomplete, seen some examples but can't find an example where it's used with jsp AND retrieves data from an Action that extends ActionSupport

Comment: For me, here's an example of a bad example: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/simple-auto-complete-for-forms/

Comment: I'd recommend the jQuery plugin. IIRC its examples get their data from actions. Extending ActionSupport isn't really relevant. If you have an example project that demonstrates an inability to get a basic autocompletes working based on the jQuery plugin I'll try to help. Adding layers of complexity before getting the basics obfuscates any real issues.

Comment: (Also, there's no reason you can't just use plain old jQuery and/or other JS frameworks--it just depends on what your needs and knowledge are.)

Comment: I've updated the git project with all that I know (which is just copying and pasting from net) - the function works but does not refresh based on input and I just really don't know what to do next

Comment: Did you push? I don't see any changes; I'll look again later. I'm not sure I understand, though; the S2 jQuery autocompleter page has a complete example: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag and there's a download of the showcase app.

Comment: OK, I'm definitely closer. I took your advice and looked at the AutocompleterTag and examined the showcase.  I now have this: '  <s:url var="remoteurl" action="homeAction"/>
     <sj:autocompleter href="%{remoteurl}" id="languages" list="%{languages}" delay="500" forceValidOption="false" />
' which kind of works that is if I remove the href="%{remoteurl}" - the autocomplete works with the complete list (not what i want but closer) but with the href - it triggers the correct function, re-sets the String[] of languages but the autocomplete function on jsp dies :o/

Comment: I will push this to git when i get to my PC that is not git-blocked (which it is at work)

Comment: OK - It's updated on github (I've downloaded and examined the zip to ensure it was correctly updated) with my changes. There's some text on the jsp to explain the problem - autocomplete working with the list that was preset before the page is loaded, but when calling method using href, list updates in the action, getter is called but the autocomplete function dies - does not show any suggestions (even though some match the term)

Comment: We have vastly different definitions of "create a simple example app that exercises the autocompleter tag". I am attempting to remove everything not related to the problem. In general, you can't just dump that much stuff on someone and expect much in return.

Comment: https://github.com/davelnewton/Cars, type "mvn jetty:run", go to "localhost:8080/cars/home.action", and type in the name of a car brand.

Comment: That's wonderful! Thank you very much! It's exactly what I was hoping for! I can see exactly how it works now - with the correct annotations etc and will easily be able to integrate this feature into the project. Thank you! How can I repay you?

Comment: No need; glad it helped.

Comment: Managed to get it all seamlessly integrated into the core project. I shall be posting the full solution here this weekend to assist others that start with the zero knowledge on how to do this as I did